# Date Time Picker in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

**I am trying to implement date time picker in angular material form but Iam unable to do that. Please find my code below.**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input formControlName="nextScheduledDate" mdc-datetime-picker="" date="true" time="true" type="text" id="datetimeedit"
         placeholder="Scheduled Date and Time" show-todays-date="" minutes="true" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
         edit-input="true" show-icon="true" ng-model="dateTimeEdit" name="datetimeedit"
         class=" dtp-no-msclear dtp-input mat-input">
</mat-form-field>
```

I am getting following error while implementing:

> PopupDialogComponent.html:24 ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain
>   a MatFormFieldControl.
>       at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.js:109)
>       at MatFormField._validateControlChild (form-field.js:691)
>       at MatFormField.ngAfterContentChecked (form-field.js:495)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:32324)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:32293)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:32275)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44276)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)

While adding matInput the date picker is not opening. Please help me out

Comment: <mat-form-field>
            
            <input matInput formControlName="nextScheduledDate" mdc-datetime-picker="" date="true" time="true" type="text" id="datetimeedit"
                placeholder="Scheduled Date and Time" show-todays-date="" minutes="true" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
                edit-input="true" show-icon="true" ng-model="dateTimeEdit" name="datetimeedit"
                class=" dtp-no-msclear dtp-input mat-input">

           

        </mat-form-field>

Comment: please update the question with html and typescript code

Comment: I have added the html code

Comment: The error itself saying the <mat-form-field> should have MatFormFieldControl. Means inside MatFormField you cannot use normal input tags. You have to use matInput or some else mat field.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Another approach for using DateTime picker in angular project i.e is by using mat-datetimepicker which is available to install by following commands.

```
npm i @mat-datetimepicker/core
npm i @mat-datetimepicker/moment
```

I made the  below stackblitz link for practical representation of solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vesksm-z5ahjm

References: https://github.com/kuhnroyal/mat-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

> **The following `Angular Material` components are designed to work inside a** `<mat-form-field>`:

```
<input matNativeControl> & <textarea matNativeControl>
<select matNativeControl>
<mat-select>
<mat-chip-list>
```

> **Correct Example:**

See `matInput` (It is `MatFormFieldControl`) is used inside the `MatFormField`

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>
```

> **Wrong Example:**

See `input` is used inside `MatFromField` which is not a `MatFormFieldControl`

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: While adding matInput the date picker is not opening

Comment: My opinion is not to use  <mat-form-field> for non-mat related field. Just use simple div and wrap all things inside it.

Comment: I got this code from [link] https://unpkg.com/ng-material-datetimepicker@1.17.1/index.html url

Comment: Just remove mat-form-field and use div instead.

Comment: still datepicker is not opening

Comment: What error does it showing now. Is it the same error you were getting previously? If not then the issue is something else.

Comment: There is no error but that datepicker is not openin. Can you suggest some date and time picker which will work inside form apart from this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204734/discussion-between-abhinav-ashish-and-surjeet-bhadauriya).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Angular material doesn't offer a date/time picker, just a date picker. However, you can use a regular input inside your mat-form-field and set the type to '*datetime*' instead, like this:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input formControlName="dateTimeSelect" matInput type="datetime-local" id="date" name="date" required />
</mat-form-field>
```

Just be aware that in Angular 16, a datetime picker inside a matFormField won't show the calander icon suffix to open the form. You can fix that issue by referring to this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77494009/18865220